# Unity iOS development: How to add frameworks from pods via post build script?

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

We are using the Facebook Unity SDK 15.1.0 in Unity 2019.4.40f1. This SDK has some serious bugs. One of them is that it won't add the required frameworks to the Unity-iPhone target. The project will build, but immediately crash on startup.

The frameworks are there, but in a Pod:

[image]

I can add them manually in the General => Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content section of the target:

[image]

Everything works fine then.

However, doing this after every build is quite tedious, so I would like to automate this task via a post build script. I am scratching my head about this, since I cannot find good samples online that actually work.

So my question is: How do you add a .xcframework buried in Facebook SDK's pods so it correctly shows up in the target?

Answer (score 2):

The code in the previous answer is not working. Freimworks are not added like that.

Correct code for adding facebook's frameworks (working):

```
 [PostProcessBuild(1000)]
 public static void OnPostprocessBuild(BuildTarget buildTarget, string pathToBuiltProject)  {
     if (buildTarget != BuildTarget.iOS) return;

     string projectPath = PBXProject.GetPBXProjectPath(pathToBuiltProject);
     PBXProject project = new PBXProject();
     project.ReadFromFile(projectPath);
     string mainTargetGuid = project.GetUnityMainTargetGuid();

     List<string> frameworks = new List<string> {
         "FBSDKCoreKit",
         "FBSDKGamingServicesKit"
     };
     foreach (string framework in frameworks) {
         string frameworkName = framework + ".xcframework";
         var src = Path.Combine("Pods", framework, "XCFrameworks", frameworkName);
         var frameworkPath = project.AddFile(src, src);
         project.AddFileToBuild(mainTargetGuid, frameworkPath);
         project.AddFileToEmbedFrameworks(mainTargetGuid, frameworkPath);
     }
     // Write.
     project.WriteToFile(projectPath);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the corrected answer, as stated in my answer "`This may not be 100% correct but good enough to modify it to make it work for you.`" So my answer was a guidence. Also i am using my answer for adding frameworks to xcode project so i am thinking that maybe `xcframeworks` are handled differently from normal `frameworks`.

Comment: I used this and it bult successfully, even ran the game without crashing.
But.. then archiving failed:

Asset validation failed CFBundleIdentifier Collision. There is more than one bundle with the CFBundleIdentifier value 'com.facebook.sdk.FBSDKLoginKit' under the iOS application

Answer (score 1):

Here is how i would do it. This may not be 100% correct but good enough to modify it to make it work for you. Basically you need to use [PBXProject.AddFrameworkToProject](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/iOS.Xcode.PBXProject.AddFrameworkToProject.html) to add frameworks.

```
#if UNITY_IOS
[PostProcessBuild(1)]
public static void ChangeXcodePlist(BuildTarget buildTarget, string pathToBuiltProject) {

    if (buildTarget == BuildTarget.iOS) {
   
        // get pbx project path
        var projPath = PBXProject.GetPBXProjectPath(pathToBuiltProject);
        if (File.Exists(projPath))
        {
            var proj = new PBXProject();
            proj.ReadFromString(File.ReadAllText(projPath));

            string mainTargetGuid = null, testTargetGuid = null, frameworkTargetGuid = null;

#if UNITY_2019_4_OR_NEWER // APIs are different for getting main unity targets changes based on versions
            mainTargetGuid = proj.GetUnityMainTargetGuid();
            frameworkTargetGuid = proj.GetUnityFrameworkTargetGuid();
#else
            mainTargetGuid = 
proj.TargetGuidByName(PBXProject.GetUnityTargetName());
            testTargetGuid = 
proj.TargetGuidByName(PBXProject.GetUnityTestTargetName());
            frameworkTargetGuid = proj.TargetGuidByName("UnityFramework");
#endif
            
            // add your frameworks here
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(mainTargetGuid))
            {
                Debug.Log("Adding targets to mainTargetGuid")
                proj.AddFrameworkToProject(mainTargetGuid, "FBSDKCoreKit.xcframework", false);
                proj.AddFrameworkToProject(mainTargetGuid, "FBSDKGamingServicesKit.xcframework", false);
            }
            // add to test target aswell if exists
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(testTargetGuid))
            {
                Debug.Log("Adding targets to testTargetGuid")
                proj.AddFrameworkToProject(mainTargetGuid, "FBSDKCoreKit.xcframework", false);
                proj.AddFrameworkToProject(mainTargetGuid, "FBSDKGamingServicesKit.xcframework", false);
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(frameworkTargetGuid))
            {
                Debug.Log("Adding targets to frameworkTargetGuid")
                proj.AddFrameworkToProject(mainTargetGuid, "FBSDKCoreKit.xcframework", false);
                proj.AddFrameworkToProject(mainTargetGuid, "FBSDKGamingServicesKit.xcframework", false);
            }

            proj.WriteToFile(projPath);
        }
    }
}
#endif
```

You can also use [PBXProject.ContainsFramework](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/iOS.Xcode.PBXProject.ContainsFramework.html) before you include the frameworks.